# Update MySQL after upgrade RHEL7 - 8 : mysql-community-client-plugins has inferior architecture

Tags: mysql, redhat

I've updated RHEL 7 to RHEL 8 with leapp, but just have problems wirh mysql update:

```
sudo dnf update
Error:
 Problem 1: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.30-1.el7.i686 has inferior architecture
  - package mysql-community-libs-8.0.30-1.el7.x86_64 requires mysql-community-client-plugins = 8.0.30-1.el7, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.30-1.el8.x86_64 and mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.30-1.el7.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.30-1.el7.x86_64
  - problem with installed package mysql-community-libs-8.0.30-1.el7.x86_64
 Problem 2: mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.30-1.el7.i686 has inferior architecture
  - package mysql-community-server-8.0.30-1.el7.x86_64 requires mysql-community-icu-data-files = 8.0.30-1.el7, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.30-1.el8.x86_64 and mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.30-1.el7.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.30-1.el7.x86_64
  - problem with installed package mysql-community-server-8.0.30-1.el7.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

The same issue as well after `sudo dnf update --nobest`

Comment: Well, it says MySQL has inferior architecture, so may be install Postgres or something

Comment: I see in a search that "inferior architecture" applying to Python and Perl -- Perhaps the real problem is with the OS or hardware??